# ARM: I2C address write waits idefenitly since I2C flag isn't set after receiving ACK

Tags: c, arm, embedded, i2c

I am developing a bare-metal ARM project using LPC2138. I2C is configured for master transmitter mode. I have used the following code for writing data to the slave. I have chosen I2C polling method.

```
#define AA  (0x04)
#define SI  (0x08)
#define STO (0x10)
#define STA (0x20)
#define I2EN    (0x40)

/* I2C0CONCLR bits  */
#define AAC     AA
#define SIC     SI
#define STAC    STA 
#define I2ENC   I2EN

void I2C0_init(unsigned char mode)
{
    PINSEL0     = 0x50;
    IO0DIR      = 0x0C;
    IO0SET      = 0x0C;

    I2C0CONCLR  = AAC | SIC | STAC | I2ENC;
    I2C0SCLL    = 0x4B;
    I2C0SCLH    = 0x4B;
    I2C0CONSET  = I2EN;
    __i2c0_mode = mode;
    __i2c0_initialised = TRUE;
}

static bool I2C0_start()
{
    I2C0CONSET  = STA;
    while(!(I2C0CONSET & SI));
    if(I2C0STAT != 0x08)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

static inline bool I2C0_slave_addr(unsigned char addr, bool rw)
{
    addr = rw ? addr | BIT_MASK_RD : addr & BIT_MASK_WR;
    I2C0DAT = addr;
    I2C0CONCLR = SIC | STAC;
    while(!(I2C0CONSET & SI));  // infinite loop here
    I2C0CONCLR = SIC;
    if(rw == I2C_WR && I2C0STAT != 0x18)
        return FALSE;
    else if(rw == I2C_RD && I2C0STAT != 0x40)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

long I2C0_write(unsigned char addr, const char *buff, unsigned long buff_len)
{
    unsigned long count = 0;
    if(!__i2c0_initialised)
            return I2C_ERROR_UNINITIALISED;
    if(!buff_len)
        return 0;
    if(__i2c0_mode == I2C_MODE_MASTER)
    {
        I2C0_start();
        I2C0_slave_addr(addr, I2C_WR);
        ..............................
        ..............................
    }
}
```

I actually simulated the code using Proteus. I2C start condition and slave address are being sent properly and the address is successfully acknowledged by the slave.

After the slave acknowledgement, the SI flag should be set again automatically as per the LPC2138 reference manual. This is not happening and because of that, the code enters into an infinite loop.
I don't understand where I went wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: Post _complete_ code: [mcve]. For all we know, you might have made a trivial mistake in your definition of `I2C0CONSET`, and the entire question is misleading and useless to anyone facing similar issues. Consider this: if you understood the problem well enough to know _for sure_ which aspects definitely weren't relevant, you probably wouldn't need to ask the question...

Comment: If it ran in the simulator and doesn't run on hardware, double check that your hardware is correct. With I2C it is important to make sure your pull up resistors are strong enough but not too strong, and that all devices on the bus will accept the same voltage ranges. I don't know anything about the LPC series to help, other than this suggestion.

Comment: And change all names starting with underscores. Such names are reserved for the implementation and shall not be used by an application.